# perl: executing multiple systems processes and waiting for them to finish

Tags: perl, bash, logging, fork

Currently in my Perl script I make a call like the following:

```
system(" ./long_program1 & ./long_program2 & ./long_program3 & wait ");
```

I would like to be able to log when each of the long running commands executes while still executing them asyncronously. I know that the system call causes perl to make a fork, so is something like this possible? Could this be replaced by multiple perl fork() and exec() calls?

Please help me find a better solution.

Comment: Do you want to log the end times or just the start times? What information do you want to log when the process is started, and what inforamtion do you want to log when the process exits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, definitely. You can fork off a child process for each of the programs to be executed.

You can either do `system()` or `exec()` after forking, depending on how much processing you want your Perl code to do after the system call finishes (since exec() is very similar  in functionality to `system(); exit $rc;`)

```
foreach my $i (1, 2, 3) {
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid==0) { # child
        exec("./long_program$i");
        die "Exec $i failed: $!\n";
    } elsif (!defined $pid) {
        warn "Fork $i failed: $!\n";
    }
}

1 while wait() >= 0;
```

Please note that if you need to do a lot of forks, you are better off controlling them via [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) instead of doing forking by hand.

Comment: `exec` is not equivalent for `system` & `exit` in a number of ways. (In fact, `system` uses `exec`.)

Comment: @ikegami -  True, I oversimplified since it was not too relevant to main Q. I'll re-word

Answer (score 3):

Two alternatives:

---

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

sub launch {
   open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
   return open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR', @_);
}

my %children;
for my $cmd (@cmds) {
   print "Command $cmd started at ".localtime."\n";
   my $pid = launch($cmd);
   $children{$pid} = $cmd;
}

while (%children) {
   my $pid = wait();
   die $! if $pid < 1;
   my $cmd = delete($children{$pid});
   print "Command $cmd ended at ".localtime." with \$? = $?."\n";
}
```

I use `open3` since it it's shorter than a even trivial `fork`+`exec` and since it doesn't misattribute `exec` errors to the command you launch like a trivial `fork`+`exec`.

---

```
use threads;

my @threads;
for my $cmd (@cmds) {
   push @threads, async {
      print "Command $cmd started at ".localtime."\n";
      system($cmd);
      print "Command $cmd ended at ".localtime." with \$? = $?."\n";
   };
}

$_->join() for @threads;
```

Comment: What is the advantage to using multiple threads rather than multiple processes in a situation like this?

Comment: @Blaskovicz, It doesn't use threads instead of processes. It launches exactly the same processes. As for the advantage of the code in the second snippet over the code in the first snippet, it should be obvious: simplicity.

Comment: The threads using option is beautiful, clean and works a treat! Thanks!