# Not wait for the computation and runs next

Tags: matlab, perl

I have written a code which calls Matlab and then runs an `*.m` file (here `main.m`) using:

```
system('matlab -r main');
```

After this line there are some other computations which not use any results from Matlab file. When I run the perl code it goes to next line instead of waiting for completing the computation by Matlab, and then it finishes the whole code while Matlab is still running. I put a pause right after the above command, but because I do not want to use any pause/key in the whole code this is pitty

My question is that is there any way which the code waits for the running of Matlab and then runs the next line?

**Edit**:

I look at the question which was suggest by [PYPL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984756/pypl), but I think that question is the answer for waiting inside `system`, where my problem is that outside if system and passes from `system` very quick and won't wait to finish the `system()`.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253883/perl-executing-multiple-systems-processes-and-waiting-for-them-to-finish

Comment: @PYPL I edited my question.

Comment: Here is another solution (I'm pretty sure i have used this before): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380516/how-can-i-use-perls-system-call-to-spawn-independent-threads

Comment: @PYPL I used both method but does not work at all. 
`First Link:` As soon as start Matlab then runs next. `Second Link:`even I divided my perl script into two files and called these two files from a main file to use the second link you've mentioned, but unfortunately it doesn't work, too. Please Help!!
**PS: I think this question is not a duplicate from both mentioned link and should be open!**

Comment: There is no way the second method is not working, you can view my example here:  http://txt.do/a6ee2, i just wrote the code where 2 codes are counting a number and outprints them, as you can see `Thread Count` is the program which is running in a thread and they both work parallel

Comment: @PYPL Can you please show me your method in this simple example:   http://textuploader.com/a6e8e. I am confused somehow!

Comment: my shown code was totally enough for you to do it yourself, but here is another example: http://txt.do/a68ku pay attantion to comments